# Alfresco New Production(server) system Installation

Tags: alfresco

I will install Alfresco in a new production system(Server System). So what are System(server) configuration need for following requirements?

Here are my requirements:

- No.Of.Users=100
- No Doc Transactions per day=1000
- Desired Throughput=3.472222

Comment: A throughput of 3.47 apples per user? pairs of socks per sysadmin? You'll need to give us a bit more to go on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind of server you are using. [Here is the list](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Server_Installation) of articles on Alfresco wiki about alfresco installation on various servers.

For better performance you need to do JVM tunning. [Here is article](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JVM_Tuning) about it.